# In Jmeter, mandatory validation error is showing in response even though the key has correct values in the request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Request:

```
POST data:
--RSTXvNAvF6qiZc6NOcKWqw9HHxFBxbOOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ProjectUID"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

127
--RSTXvNAvF6qiZc6NOcKWqw9HHxFBxbOOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Customer"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

23
--RSTXvNAvF6qiZc6NOcKWqw9HHxFBxbOOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LoansInsertedVia"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Single
--RSTXvNAvF6qiZc6NOcKWqw9HHxFBxbOOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LoanNumber"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

loan0106_3
--RSTXvNAvF6qiZc6NOcKWqw9HHxFBxbOOrs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ProductUID"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

8
```

Response:

`{"validation_error":1,"message":" Please complete all mandatory fields","Customer":"This Field is required","LoanNumber":"This Field is required","Single-ProductUID":"This Field is required","Single-ProjectUID":"This Field is required"}`

Answer (score 1):

Try unticking `Use multipart/form-data` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, it might be the case your server expects "normal" [form-data](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) parameters, not the [multipart](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) ones.

[image]

Also if you're capable of successfully executing your request with the browser you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: Hi Dmitri - please leave the edit be. Your complaint is generally good advice, but there's no need to add it to answers - answers are to be addressed to a wide audience, not just the OP.

Comment: If you wish to preserve the advice to the OP then you can add it as a comment under the question (I personally would not bother, but I agree with the sentiment).